# Icefaces (ace) FileEntry direct submit without a "h:commandbutton" for avoid double click on import button

Tags: file-upload, import, double-click, icefaces-3

How to avoid double click on Import button when using a ace:fileEntry?

```
-----------------------------------
|                   ------------- |   ----------
| C:\temp\test.csv  | Browse... | |   | Import |     <------ Avoid dblclick 
|                   ------------- |   ----------
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching a solution for avoid a double-click on import button of icefaces FileEntry component.
I found a simple solution, the only requirement is to use jQuery.

*Fragment code:*

```
<ace:fileEntry styleClass="PEFileEntry1Class" fileEntryListener="#{fileImportComponent.fileValidation}" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery('.PEFileEntry1Class').change(function() {
      jQuery('.iceFrm').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Explanation:
Icefaces  component doesn't have standard event (onclick, onchange, etc) then I can use jQuery to add which I need. I added a "onChange" event and when this one is fired I call directly the submit of my formular.
That's it! :-)